# Timing mental arithmetic training for specific event

Tags: intelligence, brain-training

A test will take place in two months time. It will take place on 12:00 PM, and the test takes one hour. One has to perform tasks such as a basic IQ test, mental arithmetic and solving a sudoku. These types of tasks are known in advance.

Someone wants to train for this event by performing the tasks on a regular basis. What would be a good training schedule? Would it be best to train every day for an hour at exactly 12:00 PM, to condition the brain, or would it be better to train at random times to improve the brain's flexibility? Also, would it be better to take days off to have the brain rest, like you would do when training your body?